# Error from InjectorGenerator

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, dependencies, dart-polymer

So, i apparently upgraded my pub dependencies and now I cant start my webApp anymore, getting many errors. I tried downgrading the dependencies, but it did not help.

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: division
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  bwu_polymer_routing: any
  core_elements: '>=0.1.1+2 <0.5.0'
  di: '>=3.3.2 <5.0.0'
  http: any
  intl: any
  js: any
  polymer: any
  unittest: 0.11.3
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html

- di
```

And many Error Messages for each custom-element i have for example:

```
[web] GET /index.html => division|web/index.html
[web] GET /packages/web_components/platform.js => web_components|lib/platform.js
[web] GET /packages/web_components/interop_support.js => web_components|lib/interop_support.js
[web] GET /packages/polymer/src/build/log_injector.css => polymer|lib/src/build/log_injector.css
[web] GET /packages/web_components/dart_support.js => web_components|lib/dart_support.js
[web] GET /packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js => polymer|lib/src/js/polymer/polymer.js
[web] GET /packages/core_elements/src/core-focusable/polymer-mixin.js => core_elements|lib/src/core-focusable/polymer-mixin.js
[web] GET /packages/browser/dart.js => browser|lib/dart.js
[web] GET /packages/core_elements/src/core-focusable/core-focusable.js => core_elements|lib/src/core-focusable/core-focusable.js    
[Error from InjectorGenerator on division|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart]:
Could not load asset division|web/components%255Csmall%255Cradio-group.dart
...
```

Comment: Adding code_transformers: '<= 0.2.5' into the dependencies fixed it magically. But i'm actually not sure why. 
Someone got a clue why?